# Flex 4.5 Mobile Component Overview - where is it?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

I guess I just entered the wrong search phrases or is there really no overview of all the components that are useable on the mobile device?

I want a list/table that says: Instead of component A better use B for your mobile application because it has touch support...
Ideally this overview would also name all components that have been newly introduced for mobile development together with a picture.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out tour de flex mobile: http://flex.org/tour-de-mobile-flex/

That should be enought together with the link that Chad posted. But I agree, a Page that puts the things from tour de flex mobile together with the mentioned list would be desireable - searching samples on the phone is not that perfect...

Answer (score 3):

Check out this list [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSf3db6597adcd110e19124fcb12ab3a1c319-8000.html). I think it covers what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This post has a table of [mobile-optimized components](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile-development-flex-flashbuilder.html).  It includes a lot of good information.

Note that most everything else in the Spark space is available.  You might just need to create your own mobile skin to make it work well.